# Swift - Fetching one to many data and displaying it in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entity:
swimingPool
Parameter

swimming pool has a one to many relation to parameter (each swimming pool has many parameter). I also have an inverse relation

I have saved my data and i fetch the swimming pool in order to display the parameters

Now i'm trying to display them in a tableview. Here's my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ParamCell", for: indexPath) as! ParamCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
    return cell
}


 func configureCell(cell: ParamCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let swimmingPool = controller.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
    let parameter = swimminPool.parameters?.allObjects

    let paramArray = parameter
    for param in paramArray! {
        cell.configureCell(parameter: param as! Parameter)
    }

}
```

and here's the number of rows in section

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = controller.sections {
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        if sectionInfo.numberOfObjects > 0 {
            return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
        } else {
            let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
            noDataLabel.text = "insert a parameter"
            noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            noDataLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
            noDataLabel.numberOfLines = 2
            noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center
            tableView.backgroundView = noDataLabel
            tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

This is how i fetch data:

```
func attemptFetch() {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<SwimmingPool> = SwimmingPool.fetchRequest()

    let dataSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "swimminPoolCreatedAt", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [dataSort]


    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    controller.delegate = self
    self.controller = controller

    do {
         try controller.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error.debugDescription)")
    }
} //End AttemptFetch
```

here's how i manage the different cases:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    switch(type){
    case.insert:
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break

    case.delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break

    case.update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ParamCell
            configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        }
        break
    case.move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath{
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        if let indexPath = newIndexPath{
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
        break
    }
}
```

My problem is that the table is displaying just one result randomly(I have inserted 3 parameters)

Any idea?

Comment: You are overwriting each parameter with the following. In terms of CoreData your table view is a one-to-one view. To display all parameters perform a segue to a detail view controller, pass the swimming pool instance and populate the detail data source array with the associated parameters. Alternatively use different sections one per pool

Comment: @vadian this is actually the table where i should use the segue to display the detailsview... i'm doing the same thing with the swimming pool and it's working perfectly.. i'm not sure to understand what you have suggested...but i can see that paramArray gives me 3 value... and then when it goes in the for loop... it return just one value...

Comment: Then `controller` is supposed to contain the parameter array. Please add the code how `controller` is populated?

Comment: @vadian i have this var controller: NSFetchedResultsController<SwimmingPool>!

Comment: I don't get it. Is this the main view controller or the detail view controller?

Comment: @vadian this is the main controller where i will display a list of all the associated parameter. By clicking on one parameter the user will segue to the parameter detail

Comment: Then this is the wrong approach. You would need to use sections: The pool is the section and the parameters are the rows. Or a third level: 1st level pool, 2nd level parameters of a specific pool, 3rd level details of a specific parameter.

Comment: @vadian so in numberOfRowsInSection i should not return the numberOfObject as i wrote in my code up?

Comment: Your fetch request is straight without considering sections. It won't work this way. Consider the three level design as described in my previous comment. And don't use `NSIndexPath` in Swift 3 at all.

Comment: @vadian That was my original problem... i wasn't sure on how to fetch the parameters for the specific pool... so i fetched the pool... probably i should change my fetch request in the attemptFetch func?

Comment: @vadian many thx for all your time!! i do really appreciate it! :) anyway the error was in numberOfRowsInSection. I was returning the wrong number... returning swimminPool.paraemters?.count gives me the right amount of row!! really appreciate your help!! thx a lot!